# setting 'replace_original' to false while responding to Slack message action request doesn't work

Tags: slack-api

**Background:**
I am using the python slack API (slackclient) to build an iterative sequence of data-gathering actions in ephemeral messages.

The core of this works fine. After processing the incoming request that contains the user's interaction with a set of message buttons (or menus), I respond immediately with a JSON body, as described in the "Responding right away" [section of the official slack docs](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#responding_to_message_actions).

**The problem:**
Every response *replaces* the preceding message+attachments. In many cases, this is what I want, but there are situations where I want to add a response rather than replace the previous message.

Per the [slack docs](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#responding_to_message_actions),setting `replace_original` to false should do just that. But the following code, snipped from my handling of a simple button click (for example), replaces the original button (and the text message to which it was attached):

```
        r = {
            'response_type': 'ephemeral',
            'text': 'foo',
            'replace_original': 'false'
        }
        log.debug("Returning: {}".format(json.dumps(r)))
        resp = Response(response=json.dumps(r),
                        mimetype="application/json",
                        status=200)
        return resp
```

I have tried this with and without the `delete_original` and `response_type` fields, with no change.

**In short, it appears that in this case the `replace_original` field isn't doing anything at all; behavior is always as if it were set to 'true'.**

I feel like I must be missing something here - any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple solution here: the slack API is expecting a boolean, not a string. So `'replace_original': 'false'` in the above snippet ends up as `{"response_type": "ephemeral", "text": "foo", "replace_original": "false"}` after the `json.dumps()` call, which is invalid.

Instead, setting `'replace_original': False` becomes `{"response_type": "ephemeral", "text": "foo", "replace_original": false}`, which then has the expected behavior

Comment: > This was not a slack problem in any manner - just user error

Don't be too harsh (on yourself)! Slack documentation's sample code wraps the boolean in quotes. See the "Updating a source message in response" section in  https://web.archive.org/web/20200903030848/https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling

Comment: Yes, indeed! (That's why I answered my own question, once I figured that out. ;) )